# Reading multiple .csv files for training and testing in tensorflow

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I am just a beginner working with tensorflow. I wrote a code in python that was reading a single .csv file and was splitting it into training and testing. Here is how I did that:

```
diode_df=pd.read_csv("./fun.csv", sep=",",names=['voltage','current'])
```

But now, I have about 1000 .csv files each having feature and label columns. I want to read say 900 files out of 1000 for training and rest 100 files for testing. Can anyone help how to do that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

files = os.path.listdir('./')
train = pd.DataFrame()
test = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
  df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=",",names=['voltage','current'])
  if i < 900:
    train.append(df)
  else:
     test.append(df)
```

Comment: This ruins boundaries.